# How to safely hold passwords in app?

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I made a site where people can sign in and 'do something'. 
Now I want to create Android application which be a client apk (people could do things similar to page).

**Question**:

1. Php is server-side language, so its more secure to store passwords (for ex. to mysql) in .php than in android apk. Which are the best way to store passwords in android application?

Comment: Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [Modern, Secure, Salted Password Hashing Made Simple](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes)